# One is defined and other is from a mapped object options for select box in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have here a `select` field wherein I have a defined string as an option and the other one is mapped from `@reps` object

It keeps on saying `undefined method 'map' for nil class`

Snippet:

```
= f.select :representative, [@reps.map{|me| [me.select_name, me.id]},["Other"]], :autofocus => true
```

Any workarounds will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well first, you need to make sure @reps is not nil. You could check in the controller to set it to empty array `[]` in case it is nil just before rendering.

Second, you need to properly merge your arrays and keep the structure intact. The additional option also needs an (empty) id.

```
@reps.map{|me| [me.select_name, me.id]} << ['Other','']
#     [ ['repsname1', 1], ['repsname2', 2], ['Other', ''] ]
```

With your approach, your object would look like this, which is not what you want

```
[ [['repsname1', 1], ['repsname2', 2]], ['Other'] ]
```

Comment: But the error is undefined method `merge' for [["1251241-Lesch", 4]]:Array what does it mean?

Comment: Whoops, there was an error after all. Fixed the merge. The `<<` operator adds an element to the array. `merge` is only available to hashes, not arrays. Sorry about that.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You're so awesome. Saved a lot of research time. ++ for you

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
= f.select :representative, [@reps.map{|me| [me.select_name, me.id]},["Other", '']], :autofocus => true
```

Comment: You would still need to flatten the array, wouldn't you?